# analogous mechanical electrical system- LTSPICE

Tags: ltspice

I have created a basic series and parallel rlc circuit in LTPSICE.
According to this http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Analogs/ElectricalMechanicalAnalogs.html and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/control_systems/control_systems_electrical_analogies_mechanical.htm we can see that the output must be same if the values are interchanged.

In the circuit I used an inductor of 1 H, a capacitor of 5 mF and a resistor of 260.8u\$\Omega\$ for the series RLC.
For the parallel RLC we have to interchange L and C values and R=1/R as shown in the links. So, R=1/0.0002608, C=1F and L=0.005H. But I am not able to get the same output.

Can somebody help me with it?

[image]

The current in series rlc :
[image]

The voltage in parallel rlc:
[image]

Comment: What is "output"? Voltage? Current? Both?

Comment: according to the links the voltage across capacior in series circuit should be equal to current across the inductor in parallel circuit

Comment: Sorry, how do you get "voltage" to equal "current"?

Comment: Hi Solar Mike, check out the link. I am trying to do a mechanical circuit analogous to electrical. There are 2 methods to do that. And according to the formulas it should be same in 2 methods as shown in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/control_systems/control_systems_electrical_analogies_mechanical.htm .

Comment: I don't see anywhere in that link where it shows Voltage is equal to Current... But as your question has been edited...

Comment: The series RLC has a voltage source (=force input) and the output here is "current" (=velocity), the parallel RLC has a current source (=force input) with output "voltage" (=velocity). The shapes of both outputs should be equal as both represent velocity

Comment: I hope you are comparing the *current* for the voltage input, and the *voltage* for the current input.

Comment: Both velocities are the same... (i made an error in my LTSpice). As @aconcernedcitizen and I indicate: do compare the current of the series RLC with the voltage of the parallel RLC.

Comment: Hi @aconcernedcitizen and Huisman, I have compared current in series rlc and voltage in parallel rlc. They are not the same over time. for the analysis of 100sec The voltage in parallel rlc decreases very fast but the current in the series circuit is almost the same even after 100 sec.

Comment: Right click on the inductors and set the series resistance to 0.

Comment: I have added the screenshots of the current in series rlc and voltage in parallel rlc.

Comment: You are exiting an RC tank which is damped out by R eventually (increase stop time to e.g. 10000 sec). But with the **default series resistance** in both the inductors, this goes even faster.

Comment: @Huisman, that did the trick I believe. Thank you so much. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The resistance values you are using are extremely low in one case and extremely low in the other. Most simulators assume the resistances are in the range 1 milli-ohm to 1-gigohm. The simplest solution is to rescale your analogue (usually by a factor of 1000) , e.g by making kN = amps or mm/sec = volt,  You want to get the resistance of 260.8uΩ to change to 260.8mΩ and R=1/0.0002608 to change to R=1/0.2608.
With resonant circuits, what is most important is the "Q" of the circuit, which is simply the **ratio** of reactive impedance to resistance , which is also the ratio of mass to damping.

The other way to fix this is to get into the simulator settings, then change  things like "minimum current step" or "minimum time step"  or "minimum error" or "minimum resistance", the instructions for your simulator will tell you what to try. (I haven't used LTspice for decades, so can't tell you the particulars)